# http.Post in go not working?

Tags: go

I'm trying to hit a file upload API with this bit of go code in a cli tool.  The post doesn't seem to even hit the server, but this code runs with no error, and the result message is an empty string.

curl works.
Other Posts work.

Any advice?

```golang
file, err := os.Open(c.Args().Get(0))

if err != nil {
    exitErr(err)
}

defer file.Close()

fmt.Print("About to upload file ", c.Args().Get(0), "\n");
res, err := http.Post(fmt.Sprintf("%s/upload", config.Host), "application/octet-stream", file)
if err != nil {
    exitErr(err)
}

defer res.Body.Close()

message, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

if err != nil {
    exitErr(err)
}

fmt.Print("Uploaded result: ", string(message), "\n")
```

Comment: What is the status code? How about the output of `fmt.Sprintf("%s/upload", config.Host)`

Comment: It's generally a fruitless line of thinking to start by assuming that a core function of a language used extensively in production by multiple major companies is faulty. It is extremely unlikely to be `http.Post` that isn't working, and far more likely to be either your code, your operating environment, or the remote host. Whenever an HTTP request doesn't work as expected, it's always a good idea to at least check the response code.

Comment: @Adrian, the only assumption I'm making is that I'm doing something wrong, which is why I posted that code fragment.  I'll check the response code... thanks.

Comment: [httputil.DumpResponse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse) is very useful for debugging. Wild guess: the server expects a multiparty form but you are sending the file itself in the body. Also try [curl-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/), but note that not all curl options are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers.  I never thought to check the status code.  I was getting a 307 (Temporary Redirect), not 200.  My solution is to loop around, following 'location', up to a max redirect count.  I've read that the default http client code in go follows redirects, so I'm a little surprised that I have to do this.  Both go and http programming are new to me, and I appreciate the help!